# Rals 7, jQuery, Datatables - this.each is not a function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I have an issue running with jquery 3.6.3 and I am using `datatables.net-bs4`. (I am targeting `bootstrap 4`)

I created a barebones Rails 7 App:

```
rails _7.0.4_ new rails7BStestapp -T --css=bootstrap -j esbuild
cd rails7BStestapp
yarn add jquery datatables.net-bs4
```

Then created a `load_dependencies.js` file in `app/javascript` that looks like:

```
import jquery from 'jquery'
import DataTable from "datatables.net-bs4"

window.jQuery = jquery
window.$ = jquery
window.DataTable = DataTable();
```

and finally in `app/javascript/application.js` I added:

```
import "./load_dependencies.js"
```

After creating a simple controller

```
rails g controller home index
```

and going to `localhost:3000/home/index`

In the console I get:

```
application-ca1281b74271bb2669fc8d31a6756411b650c76d13311ce2fd4b9854109592f0.js:18137 Uncaught TypeError: this.each is not a function
    at DataTable (application-ca1281b74271bb2669fc8d31a6756411b650c76d13311ce2fd4b9854109592f0.js:18137:10)
    at application-ca1281b74271bb2669fc8d31a6756411b650c76d13311ce2fd4b9854109592f0.js:23743:22
    at application-ca1281b74271bb2669fc8d31a6756411b650c76d13311ce2fd4b9854109592f0.js:23744:3
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue and my guess is that you have not included jquery in your package.json. Please add that and do `npm install`.
Let me know if I can help further.

Answer (score -1):

Always use a fallback when loading data off a server, since array/object methods will throw an exception if used on `undefined`.

For your case, you may wish to define `window.DataTable` like this instead:

`window.DataTable = DataTable() ? DataTable : [];`

Comment: Sorry, struggling to see how this in any way addresses my problem.